# Moving Average not returning floats for time series

Tags: data, time-series

I have thousands of rows of time series data in the form below:

```
{<|"date" -> "2018-01-02 22:39:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14098.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:40:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14425.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:41:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13864.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:42:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:43:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:44:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:45:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13998.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:46:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13931.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:47:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:48:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13797.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:49:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13931.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:50:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14425.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:51:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13831.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:52:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:53:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14457.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:54:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14425.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:55:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:56:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14328.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:57:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:58:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14425.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 22:59:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14065.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:00:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13864.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:01:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14490.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:02:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:03:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:04:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13558.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:05:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14295.6|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:06:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:07:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14360.7|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:08:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:09:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13831.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:10:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:11:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:12:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14230.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:13:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13661.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:14:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:15:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:16:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:17:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14360.7|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:18:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13280.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:19:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:20:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13420.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:21:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:22:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13420.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:23:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14098.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:24:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:25:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13898.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:26:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:27:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:28:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14032.|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:29:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14032.|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:30:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14098.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:31:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14164.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:32:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14098.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:33:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14230.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:34:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14164.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:35:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13524.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-02 23:36:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:44:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> ""|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:45:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13524.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:46:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:47:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:48:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14360.7|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:49:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13763.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:50:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13797.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:51:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:52:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:53:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:54:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:55:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:56:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13139.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:57:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:58:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14098.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 06:59:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:00:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12996.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:01:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:02:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:03:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14032.|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:04:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13489.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:05:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14164.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:06:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:07:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:08:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:09:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13524.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:10:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13067.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:11:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:12:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13931.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:13:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:14:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:15:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:16:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14586.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:17:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:18:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14457.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:19:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13998.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:20:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:21:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:22:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14360.7|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:23:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13998.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:24:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13280.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:25:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:26:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14393.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:27:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14360.7|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:28:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13763.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:29:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14032.|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:30:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14262.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:31:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13998.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:32:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13864.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:33:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:34:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:35:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:36:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:37:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13661.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:38:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13245.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:39:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13385.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:40:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13831.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:41:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13797.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:42:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13524.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:43:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13139.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:44:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12960.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:45:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13174.6|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:46:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12595.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:47:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12483.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:48:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12960.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:49:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13558.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:50:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:51:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13315.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:52:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12558.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:53:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:54:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13420.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:55:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:56:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13385.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:57:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13174.6|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:58:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 07:59:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13592.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:00:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13032.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:01:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:02:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12960.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:03:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13661.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:04:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12632.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:05:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12669.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:06:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12851.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:07:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:08:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12888.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:09:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13067.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:10:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13032.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:11:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12779.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:12:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12960.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:13:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13763.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:14:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:15:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13592.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:16:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12595.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:17:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:18:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13350.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:19:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:20:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13350.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:21:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:22:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:23:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13385.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:24:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13280.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:25:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13174.6|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:26:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13831.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:27:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13931.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:28:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:29:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13864.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:30:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13524.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:31:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13661.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:32:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13931.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:33:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13454.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:34:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13350.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:35:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13998.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:36:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:37:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13965.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:38:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13139.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:39:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13245.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:40:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14032.|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:41:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14197.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:42:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14065.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:43:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13420.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:44:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13695.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:45:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13067.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:46:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13797.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:47:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 14131.4|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:48:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12996.3|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:49:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 11592.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:50:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12815.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:51:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13032.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:52:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13067.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:53:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 11831.1|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:54:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13067.9|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:55:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12483.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:56:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13315.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:57:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:58:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 12408.6|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 08:59:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13489.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:00:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13558.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:01:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13627.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:02:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:03:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13729.5|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:04:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13864.8|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:05:00", 
  "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13420.2|>, <|"date" -> 
   "2018-01-04 09:06:00", "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> 13489.5|>}
```

I'm trying to do a tiny bit of processing with it with and get it into a time series format.

```
AnalyzeTime[inputAssoc_] := 
 Module[{window = Quantity[1, "Days"], 
   delta = Quantity[10, "Minutes"], assoc, var, cc, start, ts},
  ts = TimeSeries[
    inputAssoc[[All, "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn"]],
    {inputAssoc[[All, "date"]]}
    ];
  
  ts = TimeSeriesAggregate[ts, delta];
  
  ts = MovingAverage[ts, window];
  
  TimeSeriesMap[N, ts]
  ]


out = AnalyzeTime[data]
```

However when I run it I get the strangest problem with the values. One example is below:

```
out["Values"][[7]] // FullForm

(* Returns  *) 

Times[0.14285714285714285`,Plus[81469.04313333334`,Times[0.1`,Plus[126657.544`,""]]]]
```

I was expecting just a single floats as values. I tried searching the title of this question and also forcing it to a numeric value. I've checked the data values and there are no strings. If I'm reading the `Fullform` correctly a string is being introduced by `MovingAverage`? Is this replicable by anyone? Are there any suggested workarounds?

Comment: `<|"date" -> "2018-01-04 06:44:00", "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> ""|>`

Comment: The question here should be how do I clean my data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in the way that is presented it is unlikely to help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed pout by @lericr, you have non numeric data that needs to be removed.

```
<|"date" -> "2018-01-04 06:44:00", "rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn" -> ""|>
```

To remove the bad data, I use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)

```
out = AnalyzeTime[
    Select[
        data, 
        NumericQ[#["rtu_003_fltrd_sa_flow_tn"]]&
    ]
]
```